# How to reset the getters and setters of a constructor

Tags: java, constructor

in my recent uni work ive been given a task which i believe is to reassign values that have been set by getters and setters. The exact question is 
" Edit the product’s main information that shares among all class such as ID,
Description, etc"

My attempt at this question is as followed.

```
 public void editProductInformation() { //Standard level task 2 method 3

        this.ID = 456890;
        this.description = "Eggs";
        this.recommendedUnitPrice = 10;
        this.Unit = 6;
        this.weight = 750;              
    }

}
```

this is also the code for the rest of the class

```
public class Product {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    protected int ID;
    protected String description;
    protected double recommendedUnitPrice;
    protected double actualPrice;
    protected int Unit = 1;
    protected double weight;
    protected LocalDate expiaryDate;
    protected LocalDate expireDate;

    public Product(int ID, String description, double recommendedUnitPrice, int unit, double weight, LocalDate expiarayDate) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.description = description;
        this.recommendedUnitPrice = recommendedUnitPrice;
        this.Unit = unit;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.expiaryDate = expiarayDate;

    }

    public int getID() {
        return this.ID;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }

    public void setDescripption(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public double getRecommendedUnitPrice() {
        return this.recommendedUnitPrice;
    }

    public void setRecommendedUnitPrice(double recommendedUnitPrice) {
        this.recommendedUnitPrice = recommendedUnitPrice;
    }

    public int getUnit() {
        return this.Unit;
    }

    public void setUnit(int unit) {
        this.Unit = unit;
    }

    public double getWeight() {
        return this.weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(double Weight) {
        this.weight = Weight;
    }

    public LocalDate getExpiaryDate() {
        return expiaryDate;
    }

    public void setExpiaryDate(LocalDate expiaryDate) {
        this.expiaryDate = expiaryDate;
    }

    public void setPrice() {
        System.out.println("Enter the price: ");
        this.actualPrice = input.nextDouble();
    }

    public void setExpireDate() {

        System.out.println("Enter the given date: ");
        int day = input.nextInt();
        int month = input.nextInt();
        int year = input.nextInt();
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(day, month, year);
        this.expireDate = date;
    }

    public void comparePrice() { // Standard level task 2 method 1

        if (recommendedUnitPrice == actualPrice) {
            System.out.println("Price is equal");
        } else if (recommendedUnitPrice < actualPrice) {
            System.out.println("Price is less");
        } else if (recommendedUnitPrice > actualPrice) {
            System.out.println("Price is more");
        }

    }

    public void verifyExpireProduct() { //Standard level task 2 method 2

        if(expireDate == expiaryDate) {
            System.out.println("Product is expired");
        }
        else System.out.println("Product is not expired");
    }
```

I understand this question might not be explained well enough so i understand if people wish to downvote it. Any insight or help is much appreciated!

Comment: I think *Edit the product’s main information that shares among all class such as ID, Description, etc* means *Use setters (another time) to overwrite the previously set values of those class attributes all `Product`s have*. Could that be correct?

Comment: What you did looks fine. But there is not any getter/setter reset in your requirement :  "Edit the product’s main information that shares among all class such as ID, Description, etc". The fields could be set by the constructor or any way, it doesn't matter.  You just need to provide a method to update some specific fields.

Comment: @deHaar Product has 2 subclasses and objects that are created are based on the subclasses not the superclass if that changes anything.

Comment: OK, but they share the same attributes, don't they? Please give some example(s) of creating `Product`s and assigning values.

Comment: @deHaar Yup they do. So by inherintence then what ever changes in product will change in the sub classes.

Comment: Well, what does that question target then? Is it the values of instances created or is it the class attributes of the base class? It is pretty unclear to me what you are to edit exactly .

Comment: Unrelated: A) `expireDate == expiaryDate` do not use **==** for OBJECTS. Always invoke the `equals()` method instead B) dont have void methods print "results". Instead write a method "isExpired" that return true or false, and then maybe another method that calls that method to then print something. Why? Because then you can **test** things much easier. You want to verify that the result of such a check is as expected. And when the only way to know that is "by reading console output", then testing can't be automated.

Answer (score -1):

You can make an object of this class and then by using setter function defined in class you can set the value .

```
Product p1 = new Product();
p1.setId(5);
//This will set the Id to 5
```

Comment: Product also requires values when i make an object  which i dont want

Comment: so to solve this define another constructor in which no parameters are there(no parameter constructor) ,so you don't need to provide values when you make the object of class product.